# How to get the highest high and the lowest low of specific timeframe in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am currently stuck in pine script, trying to get the highest high and lowest low of specific timeframe, lets say 0000 to 0400 , of the current day

```
pdh = security(tickerid, 'D', high)
pdl = security(tickerid, 'D', low)
```

This here gets us the highest high and lowest low of this current day.
Note this is with pine script V4.

Comment: Need more info. You have intraday bar on the chart (like 1-min) and you want to get max/min of 4 first bars in a day? I can't get why you request daily resolution via security.

Comment: So it would be in the hourly timeframe, but the first 4 bars of the day according to my timezone UTC-5, and yeah i need to get those lines on the hourly timeframe but see them even when i switch timeframes thats why i used security

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why is your timezone is important? Usually it's about symbol's session first bars. Or you want something different, like for example a symbol is traded 1700-1700 in London time, but you want get the values first 4 bars in your timezone, so it'd be 0000-0400 (or maybe 1700-2100?) in your timezone?

Comment: yeah it would be 0000-0400 in my timezone ,  or 0600-1000 on london's time, yeah the goal is to be able to target certain candles by time , or high and low according to time

Comment: gave an answer below. It's only for highest, but I think you'll managed to implement lowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Highest of first 4 bars in timezone GMT-5, different from tz of symbol")
t = timestamp("GMT-5", year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute, second)
highest = -1.0

if hour(t) > 4
    highest := nz(highest[1], -1)
else
    for i = 0 to 1000
        if na(t[i]) or hour(t[i]) > 4
            break
        highest := max(highest, high[i])

plot(highest)
```

I think it should be looking similar to the code above. Maybe it works not exactly as I expect (I didn't debug nor test it), but I suppose that it'll be enough to implement required features by your own.

Comment: great it is working good for the highest, i did the same for the lowest but i think i missed something
`
lowest = -1.0

if hour(t) > 4
    lowest := nz(lowest[1], -1)
else
    for i = 0 to 1000
        if na(t[i]) or hour(t[i]) > 4
            break
        lowest := max(lowest, low[i])

plot(lowest) ,

`

Comment: lowest definitely cannot be `max` of two (or more) values ;)

Comment: I get you, sorry not very familiar with the pine language, wouldnt it be logical to replace max by min ? however when i did , it will not show anything

Comment: Yes, you've got it right. And you should change the default value of the lowest from -1 to something big (e.g. `lowest = 100000000000000000000000000000.0`). Then it should work.